# How to unhide select tag HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to do the following in HTML and JavaScript:

I am using Select tag (HTML) that will be hidden until a user clicks on No.
If the user click on No, then the Select options appears and if the user select Yes, the Select options disappear.  This function works great with input and other tags, but not select tag.

I did a lot of research and I found out that the display:none and select tag does not work with Google Chrome and IE, but all the solutions were given in JQuery and ASP.net.  Since I am still new to all of this, I was wondering if there is a solution using HTML and JavaScript?

Code HTML:

```
    <div id="divMetSpec" class="fieldRow">
     <div class="leftLabel labelWidth20">
        <label for="">Met Spec Upon Return:</label>
     </div>
     <div class="leftField">
      <div class="formField68">
        <input id="rbMetSpec" name="rbMetSpec" type="radio" 
        class="radiobuttonfield" alt="Met Spec" title="Met Spec" value="Yes"
        onclick="javascript:KitFailure();" />Yes
        <input id="rbMetSpec1" name="rbMetSpec" type="radio" 
        class="radiobuttonfield" alt="Met Spec" title="Met Spec" value="No" 
        onclick="javascript:KitFailure();" />No
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>

   <div id="KitFailure" style="display:none">
    <p class="indent">To select multiple options - Please hold down the Ctrl 
    button to select:</p>

     <div class="leftLabel labelWidth20">
        <label for="txtKitFailure">Specify Failure:</label>
     </div>    
     <div class="leftField">
      <div class="formField40">
        <select id="txtKitFailure" type="text" class="fieldRow" 
        name="KitFailure" multiple size="5">
            <option value="Failure1">Failure 1</option>
            <option value="Failure2">Failure 2</option>
            <option value="Failure3">Failure 3</option>
            <option value="Failure4">Failure 4</option>
            <option value="Failure5">Failure 5</option>
            <option value="Failure6">Failure 6</option>
            <option value="Failure7">Failure 7</option>
            <option value="Failure8">Failure 8</option>
         </select>
       </div>
      </div> 
     </div>
```

Code JavaScript:

```
  function KitFailure() {
     if (document.getElementById('rbMetSpec1').checked)  {

       document.getElementById('KitFailure').style.display = 'none';

      } else  document.getElementById('KitFailure').style.display = 'block';

     }
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Irene

Comment: You could try hiding the div that contains the select element.

Comment: @Kenji but that's exactly what he (or she) did... and the code above works in my IE 11

Comment: kay27 I have IE 11 and Google Chrome - I just can't make it work on both browsers.

Comment: @kay27 Sounded to me like Irene was trying to hide the individual elements and it wasn't working. I did see in the code that a div was being hidden, I would assume that works perfectly fine, but trying to hide the select itself does not. Irene can you please clarify?

Comment: This works if I do not use the select tag.  If I use input tag within the div, it works fine but not the select tag.  I am trying to hide everything within div.  Once the user click on No, everything in div will show.  If the user click on Yes, everything in div does not show.  I hope this helps.  Thank you

Comment: @IreneS I get the feeling this has something to do with your CSS or code that is not included here, as I am able to hide <select> with no problem in Chrome and IE 11. See this jsfiddle, it works: https://jsfiddle.net/LyrcdLx0/1/

Comment: I created it from empty file to test: put html part after <body> tag and then in the same file: <script> code javascript </script> and nothing more and it works nice in my IE11 but unfortunately couldn't test with Chrome... maybe you have any additional css or browser extensions which prevents this?

Comment: Kenji, it worked.  I just added per your codes:   document.getElementById("rbMetSpec").onclick = KitFailure;               
document.getElementById("rbMetSpec1").onclick = KitFailure; to the JavaScript file outside the function, did not change anything else.  I understand the syntax of the above codes but what did these code do to make the program work?  I am just trying to learn and understand all of this.   Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

It works as is in IE11 + emulations, FF, Chrome, and Safari for Windows.
Some corrections:
`type="text"` is not valid attribute of `select`
Also use `multiple="multiple"`

`Alt` is not valid attribute of `input`

Comment: Thank you Alexander, I have corrected my codes as you have suggested.   I really appreciate this - Little by little I am learning.  The only thing, my codes do not work with IE11 and Chrome unless I implement the codes that Kenji shared with me.  That is the only way, the show and hide works for the select tag.  Thank you all